# Javascript problems with a function not working (it converts fractions into decimals)

Tags: javascript, function, decimal, fractions

Let's say I have a string (like a fraction);

```
var num = "1/2";
```

Why does this work:

```
var y = num.split(' ');
if (y.length > 1) {
    var z = y[1].split('/');
    var a = (+y[0] + (z[0] / z[1]));
    num = a;
} else {
    z = y[0].split('/');
    if (z.length > 1) {
        a = (z[0] / z[1]);
        num = a;
    }
}

alert(num); //The alert box shows my variable now as a decimal.
```

And this doesn't:

```
function parseFractions(x) {
    var y = x.split(' ');
    if (y.length > 1) {
        var z = y[1].split('/');
        var a = (+y[0] + (z[0] / z[1]));
        x = a;
    } else {
        z = y[0].split('/');
        if (z.length > 1) {
            a = (z[0] / z[1]);
            x = a;
        }
    }
}

parseFractions(num); //Here I call my function.

alert(num);
//The alert box does not even show up. The fraction isn't converted into a decimal.
```

It's basically the same thing, the only difference is that in the 2nd one I tried to make that into a function so I don't have to repeat those lines of code every time I try to convert fractions into decimals.

So what am I doing wrong? Is what I am trying to accomplish possible with a function? Any light into this issue is appreciated!

Comment: "pass by reference" and "pass by value".

Comment: If the `alert` doesn't show up, you have a runtime error. It's probably a simple issue and you can solve it yourself if you [learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript). Set breakpoints, inspect variables... it's not hard to find out what's going on in your code.

Comment: `Uncaught type error: undefined is not a function` let me find the source of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the value of `num` is not updated, it is not passed by reference.

```
function parseFractions(x) {
    var y = x.split(' ');
    if (y.length > 1) {
        var z = y[1].split('/');
        var a = (+y[0] + (z[0] / z[1]));
        x = a;
    } else {
        z = y[0].split('/');
        if (z.length > 1) {
            a = (z[0] / z[1]);
            x = a;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

num = parseFractions(num);  //set num with the value return from the method
alert(num);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked like a charm, that also taught me something new. This is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: @wessy: So I guess the comment in the code `//The alert box does not even show up.` was  incorrect. It shows up but you are not getting the result you expected. If you ask a question, make sure you describe everything properly.

Comment: @Wyatt I did, it doesn't let me accept an answer within 5 minutes I think so I had to wait.

Comment: That makes sense, now someone has to edit it so I can un-down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your value

Add a return to the end of your function

```
return x;
```

Adn then call the function with

```
alert(parseFractions(num)); //Here I call my function.
```

Comment: You don't *need* to call it like that, look at my example.